# Swift one button 3 messages

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to Swift and I am coding on Xcode. I am trying to do like a "Hello, World!" in Swift by having an app that is just one screen, one button, and one display label.

My objective is to have three different messages appear with the click of the button. To clarify, each time I click the button it would cycle through the messages.

I tried solving it with a `switch`, here is my (unfinished attempt)

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var textBox: UILabel!

    var userTapped = false

    @IBAction func tappedMe(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let me =
        if userTapped {
            switch me {
            case me : textBox.text = "Hello, World!"
            case me : textBox.text = "Hello, Human!"
            case me : textBox.text = "OK scram."
            default : break
            }
        userTapped = true
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what I can make `me` equal to, or if my solution is even a good one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textBox: UILabel!

    let strings = ["Hello, World!", "Hello, Human!", "OK scram."]
    var tapCount = 0

    @IBAction func tappedMe(_ sender: UIButton) {
        textBox.text = strings[tapCount]
        tapCount = (tapCount + 1) % strings.count
    }

}
```

Comment: In theory, this would crash after the button was pressed `Int.max` times, but that sure would be tough to do.  You could do `tapCount = (tapCount + 1) % strings.count` instead of doing the `%` when you index strings.

Comment: Very simple! And as a computer science student I like it!

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this it would accomplish your goal if I understand it correctly:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var textBox: UILabel!

// Integer to track number of times button has been tapped
var tapCount = 0

// Max total of text variations, for this case 2 (you have three different values, but always start with zero)
let max = 2 

@IBAction func tappedMe(_ sender: UIButton) {
    // Try different conditions for value of tapCount
    switch tapCount {
        case 0: 
            textBox.text = "Hello, World!"
        case 1: 
            textBox.text = "Hello, Human!"
        case 2: 
            textBox.text = "OK scram."
        default : break
    }

    // If this is the max number of times you want to display changing text, reset tapCount to zero, otherwise increment tapCount.
    if tapCount < max {
        tapCount += 1
    } else {
        tapCount = 0
    }
} 


}
```

Comment: @vacawama - nice catch! Thanks for that. I guess I should pay closer attention. I went ahead and edited my answer

Comment: @vacawama - okay the code and comments should now accurately reflect the desired result. Just out of curiosity, why should I not cast the `tapCount` and `max` as integers to start? I've always just been so accustomed to doing that it's become second nature. Should I refrain from doing that in most instances?

Comment: Yes.  The Swift way is to avoid unnecessary type specifications.  It's not an error, but a *best practice* style thing.  Swift can infer the types of `tapCount` and `max` to be `Int` from the values you are assigning.

Comment: Okay great, thanks for the advice! I really appreciate it.

Comment: You can verify that by Option-clicking on those variables and see the type Swift is inferring.

Comment: Wow you learn something new every day!. Thanks cool...thanks!

Comment: You can simplify it further by replacing the `if tapCount < max {} else {}` with `tapCount = (tapCount + 1) % max`.

Comment: @Jake - that's a good shortcut I didn't think of, but for it to keep looping through, wouldn't he have to say `tapCount = (tapCount + 1) % (max + 1)`? Otherwise it will go 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1

Comment: @Pierce - you're right. `tapCount = (tapCount + 1) % max` would be off. `tapCount = (tapCount + 1) % (max + 1)` would work.

Comment: @Jake - I love the idea though. I need to start remembering these basic shortcuts. Makes the code so much cleaner. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This helped me understand better how switch cases work on Swift